# how to refer which element of my list triggered the event c#

Tags: c#, list, events

I have a collection and all of its element are subscribed to the event, when when the event triggers I should get the index of the element which triggered the event.

```
for (i = 0; i < vege; i++)
{  
    CanvasList[i].MouseEnter += ListNezet_MouseEnter;
}

static void ListaNezet_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    something= index_of_the_element_in_the_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void ListaNezet_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = CanvasList.IndexOf((TypeOfListElements)sender);
}
```

`sender` is the object that triggered the event. You use `IndexOf` to get its index in the list.

Comment: almost flawless answer I just had to explicitly convert sender into the class of elements of Canvaslist.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

`sender` in the event handler is the object which triggered the event.

Comment: I got that but how should I gain the index of the sender when now its on object? I cant use sender.get_the_index_of_this_element_in_the_list on an object